# Heroku Button Deployment: The content of app.json is not valid

Tags: deployment, button, heroku

I cannot message Heroku directly since I am on the free tier. Heroku refers me to Salesforce.
My GitHub repo: https://github.com/NNTin/discord-twitter-bot

When I click on the Heroku Button in the ReadMe [I get this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik4eI.png)

> The content of app.json is not valid; please see [app.json Schema](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema) for more information.
>
> The file does not contain a valid JSON entity.

I ran the file through a json checker. It is a valid json (RFC 4627).
I visit the provided app.json Schema link and compared the schema. I'm fulfilling it.

Moreover when I visit an [older fork of my project](https://github.com/lambersond/discord-twitter-bot) (some random guy I do not know forked it) and use the Heroku Button there it works.

[When I diffcheck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kSNO.png) I see nothing out of the ordinary. The website URL was changed, the repository URL value is matched to my GitHub project and the fork of my GitHub project, I changed the description since Twitter has updated their app page and I added 2 more environmental variable. I made sure that the description is shorter than the other descriptions to rule out a possible error in string max length.

If you look at the commits you see I modified app.json a couple of times in an attempt to fix it. Before that I haven't touched app.json for over a month and I know it was working perfectly fine 2 days ago.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This forum is specifically for the Salesforce product, while Heroku is owned by Salesforce the company, this is probably not the forum for this post, and you should probably check stackoverflow for more general JS/JSON questions with Heroku

Comment: [I followed the instruction that was listed on Heroku.](https://i.imgur.com/2fg2F1k.png)
> For all programming related questions related to particular languages or frameworks, please visit the Stack Overflow community. Stack Overflow is a great place to get help from fellow Heroku users by searching thousands of previous questions or asking your own. For all questions related to the Heroku platform or specific Heroku products, please visit the Salesforce Stack Exchange community.
This was not a general JSON question. It was a Heroku pipeline question.

Comment: @Ngoc-TinDanielNguyen sounds like who every wrote that blurb was a bit confused. I think you'll want to post this to stackoverflow.com which has about 30k questions tagged with heroku. You're not alone, there are 100 or so question on this site tagged with heroku probably due to the instructions you found.

Comment: @Ngoc-TinDanielNguyen can you provide a link to the page where you took the screenshot of those instructions?

Comment: @RalphCallaway There is no proper link to it. But I made a gif on how I got to that page: https://i.imgur.com/bOwkNoq.gifv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1662

It was an error with Heroku. It has now been resolved.